# How to use source command for exporting path?

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I am trying to set the path of few libraries using `source` command but its not working and says

```
dsbisht@dsbisht-ThinkCentre-E73:~/Workstation$ source .list
bash: .list: No such file or directory
```

My `list` file is in Workstation directory.

below, are the path I have given in `list` file

```
export NETCDF=/home/dsbisht/Workstation/NETCDF413
export PATH=$NETCDF/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$NETCDF/lib
export NCARG_ROOT=/home/dsbisht/Workstation/NCAR-NCL621
export PATH=$NCARG_ROOT/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$NCARG_ROOT/lib
```

I could not find the mistake as I am new to linux. How should I do that ?

Comment: Is the filename `list` or `.list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As muru suggests, your problem might just be a typo. If your file is called "list" you could source it using:

```
source list
```

or just

```
. list
```

Note the space between the . and the filename. A dot on its own is a synonym for "source ".

If your file is called ".list" (ie it is hidden), then:

```
source .list
```

or

```
. .list
```

is what you need.

Comment: I don't think files need to be executable in order to source them, do they? My `~/.bashrc` isn't.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my post accordingly.

Comment: Yeah.. error was coming because of simultaneous use of '.' and 'source' with 'list' file, its worked as "source list". Thanks for highlighting the mistake.